# How do you get the content of a meta tag across page loads using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, youtube, single-page-application

I would like to get the content of a `meta` tag on YouTube. However, when I navigate to a new page, the contents of the old page are still returned even though the page source has been updated.

Note that I am focusing on YouTube's channel pages, which act as a single-page app.

To reproduce:

1. Visit https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBVjMGOIkavEAhyqpxJ73Dw (Maroon 5's channel)
2. Run `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="title"]')` in the console; returns `<meta name="title" content="Maroon 5">`
3. Click a link under "Related Channels" in the right sidebar; for example, https://www.youtube.com/user/EdSheeran
4. Run `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="title"]')` in the console again; still returns `<meta name="title" content="Maroon 5">`

Viewing the new page source shows the `meta` tag has been updated to `<meta name="title" content="Ed Sheeran">`. I also noticed that running `document.head.querySelector('title')` in the console returns the updated `<title>Ed Sheeran - YouTube</title>` element.

Why does the `querySelector` call still return metadata from the previous page?

Comment: You can try "document.title" command.

Comment: @VolkanYılmaz That works for the page title, but I specifically need the `<meta name="title">` element.

Comment: Visit view-source:https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBVjMGOIkavEAhyqpxJ73Dw and search <title> tags, you can see it doesn't into meta section.

I think ``<meta name="title">`` element don't change when visit youtube pages.

Comment: It's not only the  title, all the meta tags are outdated. It might be worthless to update those. It's to describe a page to engines for example - and ed sheran will have the correct description from engine's perspective.

Comment: Why do you use such query selectors? Youtube has an API for programmatic stuff

Comment: @VolkanYılmaz @Adelin Ah, you are right! The `<title>` element is updated, but the `<meta ...>` elements are outdated after clicking through to a new channel. Thank you for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the querySelector call still return metadata from the previous page?

Because: *I am focusing on YouTube's channel pages, which act as a **single-page app**.*

Presumably, whoever was responsible for writing the SPA code didn't update the metadata when they updated the rest of the DOM with JS.

Requesting a fresh copy of the page from the server to view the source, gets the correct metadata because it is being generated by the serverside code and not the SPA code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was confused because the page title and content are updated, but the `<meta ...>` elements are stale after clicking through to a new channel. Detecting this and fetching the current page source solved the problem. 